# Export contourlines to serve them through WMS

Tags: r, mapping, wms

I am trying to do automatic mapping. I want to have a uncertainty map , which uncertainties are displayed by isolines. I want to export these isolines and the values associated with them and  then display them through web map service. Is it possible? by following code you can produce the contour lines

```
require(gstat)
require(lattice)
data(meuse)
data(meuse.grid)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
m <- vgm(.59, "Sph", 874, .04)
# ordinary kriging:
x <- krige(log(zinc)~1, meuse, meuse.grid, model = m)
l=as.data.frame(x)
contourplot(var1.var ~ x+y,data=l,cuts=10)
```

Comment: Why convert contour LINES to polygons? Why not serve them as lines through your web map service?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer for your question, but maybe it  can point you in the right direction:

you can generate an object from your contourplot

```
CP<- contourplot(var1.var ~ x+y,data=l,cuts=10)
```

And try to look at its structure

```
fix(CP)
```

The data about isolines is stored here:

```
x <- CP$panel.args.common[1]$x
y <- CP$panel.args.common[2]$y
z <- CP$panel.args.common[3]$z
```

But I cannot figure out now how to extract it. 
Maybe this can help you a bit.

Comment: Dear Andrey, thanks for your answer But these values are not contour values. These are the out put of object x.